# Корректное закрытие фонового загрузчика

Tags: многопоточность, winforms, .net

У меня есть компонент, который подгружает данные в фоне. Всё грузится в отдельном потоке, а обращения к форме, когда данные загружены, происходят через `ISynchronizeInvoke`. Компонент подписывается на событие `FormClosed` формы, на которой он лежит, чтобы после закрытия прибивать загрузчик установкой флага, по которому завершается поток загрузки.

Проблема в том, что это не всегда помогает. Иногда получается так, что обращение к форме происходит уже после того, как форма закрылась, и поток загрузки виснет на вызове `ISynchronizeInvoke.Invoke`. Это может возникнуть тогда, когда флаг, по которому проверяется завершение потока загрузки, ещё не установлен перед обращением к форме, но в момент обращения к форме он уже установлен, и форма закрылась.

Я попробовал сделать блокировку на проверке флага с обращением к форме и на обработчике закрытия формы, стало получше. Где-то на полгода об этом баге мы забыли - не беспокоил.

Но недавно на тормозной машине в этом месте словили взаимную блокировку. Сценарий такой:

- Фоновый поток захватил блокировку и обратился к форме
- Обработчик закрытия формы вызвался раньше метода обновления формы, вызванного из потока загрузки
- Обработчик закрытия формы пытается захватить блокировку и встаёт в очередь, так как блокировка захвачена фоновым потоком
- Но и фоновый поток ожидает ответа от пользовательского интерфейса, так как вызвал `ISynchronizeInvoke.Invoke`.

Не хотелось бы использовать грубые методы вроде Thread.Abort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, проблему решил так: вместо `Invoke` вызываю `BeginInvoke` - `EndInvoke`, между ними делаю цикл, в котором в течение 100 миллисекунд жду завершения обработки вызова и проверяю флаг завершения. Если флаг завершения установлен, выхожу без `EndInvoke`.

Comment: Выглядит как костыль какой-то.. странные дела

Answer (score 1):

Способ, гарантированно работающий без дедлоков - это отменить диспатчинг `FormClosed` в соответствующем случае и прокинуть его в `Completed` воркера.

*В коде это может выглядеть примерно следующим образом:*

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if (!taskCompleted)
    {
        worker.CancelAsync();

        // Может быть и необязательно, однако имеет смысл перестраховаться на
        // время до диспатчинга 'Completed'.
        Enabled = false;

        closePending = true;
        eventArgs.Cancel = true;
    }

private void RunWorkerCompleted(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    taskCompleted = true;
    if (closePending) Close();
}
```

Comment: Там у меня нет BackgroundWorker. Но идея понятна.